# Не находит библиотеку <SFML/Graphics.hpp> C++ ( xcode )

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, графика, sfml

Все делал по инструкциям, а конкретно в header search paths ( программа Xcode, mac os ) написал вот это "${SRCROOT}/ExternalLibraries/SFML/include" , также добавил в link binary файлы, которые были указаны в инструкции ( на скриншоте видно их ), но все равно выдает ошибку - "/Users/macos/Desktop/SFML/SFML template/SFML template/main.cpp:1:10: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found".
в папке ExternalLibraries есть папка SFML где лежат все необходимые данные.
Помогите, пожалуйста, очень хочу изучать эту библиотеку, но все никак не могу, уже 2 недели мучусь с этой проблемой.. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjVvD.jpg
Если надо еще какие-то данные, все скину

Comment: думаю, что в "${SRCROOT}" лежит не то, что Вы ожидаете.Попробуйте вместо "${SRCROOT}/ExternalLibraries/SFML/include" вбить реальный путь к этой папке, так как Вы его видите в finder (или как оно там называется).

Comment: ну вы хотя бы пробовали в консоли `ls $SRCROOT/ExternalLibraries/SFML/include`

Comment: @KoVadim я вписал реальный путь в header search paths, library search paths теперь не выдает ошибку, выдает вот такую вот штуку - https://imgur.com/a/vIdzu2T , как это можно исправить.

Comment: а вот это уже ошибка времени выполнения. Там на скрине явно видно, что оно не нашло библиотеку с аудио. То, что Вы с ней слинковались, ещё не значит, что она будет доступна. Я не люблю маки и мало что тут могу посоветовать, но в винде или линуксе я бы подложил библиотеки рядом или в каталог, доступен для бинарника.

Comment: @KoVadim эххх... И что делать в таких случаях?

Comment: искать того, кто разбирается в маках, гуглить самостоятельно, установить более дружелюбную к программисту операционную систему. Или просто скопировать эти все *.dlsym в папку к бинарнику и надеятся.

Comment: @KoVadim а что это за папка бинарника?

Comment: не папка бинарника, а папка с бинарником. собственно папка, с скопмпилированной программой